# Selecting rows from data.table

Tags: r, key, data.table

I'm using the `R` package `data.table` to read large amounts of data and analyse them. What I was wondering is why is selecting rows from a `data.table` so much slower than from a `matrix`.

```
require(data.table)

## create some random data
n = 1000
p = 1000
set.seed(1)
data.raw <- matrix(rnorm(n*p), nrow = n, ncol = p)
rownames(data.raw) <- lapply(1:n, FUN = function(x, length)paste(sample(c(letters, LETTERS), length, replace=TRUE), collapse=""), length = 10)
colnames(data.raw) <- paste0("X", 1:n)

#do the same thing as data.table
data.t   <- data.table(data.raw)
data.t[, id := rownames(data.raw)]
setkey(data.t, id)

## now select one row after the other in both matrix and data.table
system.time(for(r in rownames(data.raw)) y <- data.raw[r, ])
#    user  system elapsed                                   
#   0.016   0.000   0.017  
system.time(for(r in data.t$id) y <- data.t[r])
# user  system elapsed
# 30.580   0.000  30.608
```

Even for this relatively small example, `data.table` is extremely slow even though using the `setkey`. Is there any way to improve the performance of this?

Comment: There is a lot of overhead in `[.data,table` compared to the default `[`. Overhead that is usually overcome by the uberfast grouping/aggregation ability of `data.table`. It's not clear what do you want to accomplish. Just selecting one row at the time doesn't look to have much sense. If you could describe better your real problem, someone will show you how to exploit the full power of `data.table`.

Comment: For example, if we were to compare subsetting, e.g., 300 rows at a time, already the speed of `data.table` begins to outweigh the `[.data.table` overhead. Compare `system.time(replicate(1000, data.raw[sample(nrow(data.raw), 300), ]))` to `system.time(replicate(1000, data.t[sample(nrow(data.raw), 300)]))`.

Comment: What I want to do is run one regression model for each row of the `data.table` against some other variables that are stored in another object. This is why I choose one row after the other.